# Attaching new drives to raid adapter

Tags: hardware-raid

I'm new to raid configurations, did only software raids until now. There is a server with a raid adapter that can have 4 drives attached to it. Currently it has 2 hdd, each with 1 TB. From the OS (CentOS 6) I see this raid as one sda1, side note question is it not md_ because it's not software raid?

Looking at the server remotely it seems like the adapter has created this raid partition by itself. The owner of the server asked if he could attach 2 more ssd with 250 GB each to the free slots so to have another raid partition. I have no clue if the adapter would add those SSDs to the existing raid partition or will create a new one. Or is it configurable from BIOS?

Please, give your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> side note question is it not md_ because it's not software raid?

Yes, that's correct. The hardware RAID controller presents its array(s) to the OS as a standard SCSI device.

> I have no clue if the adapter would add those SSDs to the existing
>   raid partition or will create a new one. Or is it configurable from
>   BIOS?

The RAID controller will not do anything with new drives automatically. You'll need to either go into the RAID card configuration (via a key combination during system boot) or by installing and using the card configuration application for your specific RAID card. With either of those options, what you're able to do with the new drives (add them to current array or create new array) will depend on the capabilities of the specific RAID card you're using.